# How do I know if this project is a class library or a console app in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Recently, I am working on a solution where there are many types of projects created in Visual Studio. But even looking at the icon I can't figure out if it's a class library or something else. How can I understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer, then select "Properties." In the properties window, check the "Output Type" under the "Application" tab. Class libraries will have "Class Library" selected as the output type.